# HTML table: column width percentage

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 7 columns. I want the columns to be of the following widths:

- 3 columns x `width=20%`
- 4 columns x `width=10%`

I have created 2 CSS classes, one per width and I am assigning them to each cell.

The thing I have, and that does not work is this. Instead, the width always wraps the content. If I just put one letter, than the width will be very small, if I put large string, the width will be too big. I want it constant.

CSS & HTML :

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.ten {
  width: 10%
}
.twenty {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="ten">H1</th>
    <th class="ten">H2</th>
    <th class="ten">H3</th>
    <th class="twenty">H4</th>
    <th class="twenty">H5</th>
    <th class="twenty">H6</th>
    <th class="ten">H7</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="ten">A1</td>
    <td class="ten">A2</td>
    <td class="ten">A3</td>
    <td class="twenty">A4</td>
    <td class="twenty">A5</td>
    <td class="twenty">A6</td>
    <td class="ten">A7</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="ten">B1</td>
    <td class="ten">B2</td>
    <td class="ten">B3</td>
    <td class="twenty">B4</td>
    <td class="twenty">B5</td>
    <td class="twenty">B6</td>
    <td class="ten">B7</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Could someone explain how to achieve what I want?

Comment: I turned your code into a snippet, and it works as expected.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

To fix width, you can use [`table-layout:fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) .

You may also want to use the [`colgroup` and `col`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup) tags to assign at once width and bg to your columns.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.ten {
  width: 10%;
  background: tomato;
}
.twenty {
  width: 20%;
  background: turquoise
}
/* see me */
td {
  border: solid;
}
/* play with bg cells and cols ? */

tr:nth-child(even) :nth-child(odd) {
  background:rgba(100,255,50,0.3);
  }
tr:nth-child(odd) :nth-child(even) {
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="ten" />
    <col class="ten" />
    <col class="ten" />
    <col class="twenty" />
    <col class="twenty" />
    <col class="twenty" />
    <col class="ten" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>H1</th>
    <th>H2</th>
    <th>H3</th>
    <th>H4</th>
    <th>H5</th>
    <th>H6</th>
    <th>H7</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>A4</td>
    <td>A5</td>
    <td>A6</td>
    <td>A7</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>B4</td>
    <td>B5</td>
    <td>B6</td>
    <td>B7</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>A4</td>
    <td>A5</td>
    <td>A6</td>
    <td>A7</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>B4</td>
    <td>B5</td>
    <td>B6</td>
    <td>B7</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your CSS works as expected, in a way that the widths of the table heads and cells are correct. However:

`th` by default have text-align: center applied, while the `td` element has not.

So you should add either to the td or th the same text alignment. E.g.:

```
th {
    text-align: left;
}
```