# Columns Width are different in most chrome versions and Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have Programmed in MVC which works fine. but in a few chrome browser the columnd widths are different. This is correct Table

[image]

You can see the red underline and this is the wrong one.

[image]

as you can see the first three columns are wider than they should be.

this is the code

```
  <div class="col-md-9" style="background-color:gainsboro">

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class=" display stripe row-border  order-column"  id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                 <th style="width:1%">fld_Id</th>
                <th style="width:1%">ref_Id</th>
                <th style="width:1%">Letter_Id</th>
                <th style="width:1%">Flags</th>
                <th style="width:1%">Status</th>
                <th style="width:1%">كد</th>
                <th style="width:1%">نوع</th>
                <th style="width:29%">ارجاع دهنده</th>
                <th style="width:30%">موضوع ارجاع</th>
                <th style="width:30%">موضوع نامه</th>
                <th style="width:1%">تاريخ دريافت</th>
                <th style="width:1%"></th>
                <th style="width:1%"></th>
                <th style="width:1%"></th>                   
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>           
    </table>

</div>
```

I am using MVC , Bootstrap v3.0.0, DataTable jquery. how can I find the problem to make them look the same in different borwsers?

***Edit Section:***
The Data inside of the Table will be populated by DataTable Jquery server Side. So I made the Client Side DataTable . The result was Ok and no difference in different Browser. when I use the Server Side DataTable the difference will be shown

This is the code that I use to populate the DataTable

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    

var BindDataTable = function (clicked_id) {             
    var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/Main/GetLetterList",
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "fld_id", "value": boldMenu });
            $.ajax({                 
                type: "Get",
                data: aoData,
                url: sSource,
                dataType: "json",
                success: fnCallback,
                error: function (response) {

                        window.location.href = '/ACCLogin/Login/';
                }
            })

        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function () {
            var UnBoldMenu = "#" + $("#unBoldMenu").val();
            $("#ulTreeview").find(UnBoldMenu).css('font-weight', 'normal');
        },
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
            if (aData["Flags"] == "4") {
                $('td', nRow).css('font-weight', 'bold');
            }
            if (aData["Status"] == "1") {
                $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');

            }
        },
        "aoColumns": [

            { "mData": "fld_Id" },
            { "mData": "ref_Id" },
            { "mData": "Letter_Id" },
            { "mData": "Flags" },
            { "mData": "Status" },
            { "mData": "ProjectCode" },
            { "mData": "LetterType" },
            { "mData": "Referrer" },
            { "mData": "Ref_subject" },
            { "mData": "Letter_subject" },
            { "mData": "Date_Received" },
            {
                "mData": "ref_Id",
                "render": function (ref_Id, aoData, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a href="#" onclick="ViewLetter(' + ref_Id + ')" title="مشاهده نامه"><li class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></li></a>'
                }
            }, {
                "mData": "ref_Id",
                "render": function (ref_Id, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a href="#" onclick="ReferenceLetter(' + ref_Id + ')" title="ارجاع نامه"><li class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></li></a>'
                }
            }
            , {
                "mData": "Letter_Id",
                "render": function (Letter_Id, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a href="#" onclick="ReferenceList(' + Letter_Id + ')" title="گردش نامه"><li class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet"></li></a>'
                }
            }

        ]
     })
        .columns.adjust();

    if (clicked_id!=-16)
        table.columns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]).visible(false); 
    else
        table.columns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4,12]).visible(false); 


}


var ViewLetter = function (refId) {
        var url = "/Main/ViewLetter?Ref_Id=" + refId;
        $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
        $("#myModalBodyDiv").load(url, function () {
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
        })
}

var ReferenceLetter = function (refId) {
    var url = "/Main/ReferenceLetter?Ref_Id=" + refId;
            $("#myModalBodyDivRefer").load(url, function () {
                $("#myModalRefer").modal("show");
        })
}


var ReferenceList = function (letterId) {
    var url = "/Main/ReferenceList?Letter_Id=" + letterId;
    $("#myModalBodyDivReferList").load(url, function () {
        $("#myModalReferList").modal("show");
    })
}



</script>
```

I call BindDataTable  on document.ready

Comment: To set column widths on an HTML table apply [widths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) with CSS to [`<col>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) or [`<colgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup) elements.

Comment: The sum of the widths are 101%. I vaguely remember it that the sum must be 100%. I think that the browser otherwise might start to make up its own widths. Your first columns have no width, you need to specify the widths on those columns also.

Comment: @mortb: I edited the widths to have correct sum and set the first four row style="width:1%", but no success

Comment: @Richard: I set it in style "style="width:1%""

Comment: You are only setting on the header cells, the data cells can and will push columns wider: this is why the abiity to set the width of a column or group of columns was added.

Comment: @nnmmss: you need to set the width in these fields also:  `<th>fld_Id</th>
                <th>ref_Id</th>
                <th>Letter_Id</th>
                <th>Flags</th>
                <th>Status</th>` Otherwise the browser might just put random widths

Comment: @mortb: I did it in version 2 as you told. but the result was the same

Comment: @Richard: The Table is populated by DataTable Jquery. so there is no td. When I use ClientSide Datatable it is ok. but when I use server Side DataTable the difference happens

Comment: Try fixed layout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654751/html-table-column-width-percentage
I think that the columns that have `width="1%"` are too small some of them contains images and will render as larger than one percent, since the image can't be wrapped to several lines.

Comment: There will be `<td>` elements: they'll be generated client side, but they will still be there (take a look with your browser's dev tools).

Answer (score 0):

I set the width of each column from Jquery and remove it from . so the code is like this:

```
 <div class="col-md-9" style="background-color:gainsboro">

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class=" display stripe row-border  order-column"  id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>fld_Id</th>
                <th>ref_Id</th>
                <th>Letter_Id</th>
                <th>Flags</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>كد</th>
                <th>نوع</th>
                <th>ارجاع دهنده</th>
                <th>موضوع ارجاع</th>
                <th>موضوع نامه</th>
                <th>تاريخ دريافت</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>                    
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>           
    </table>

</div>
```

and set the width in jquery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var CategoryClick = function (clicked_id) {
    var boldMenu = $("#boldMenu").val();
    if  (boldMenu != clicked_id)
        $("#unBoldMenu").val(boldMenu);
    $("#boldMenu").val(clicked_id);
    var str = "#" + clicked_id;
    $("#ulTreeview").find(str).css('font-weight', 'bold');
    BindDataTable(clicked_id);
}

var BindDataTable = function (clicked_id) {  //response
    var boldMenu = $("#boldMenu").val();
     if (@User.Identity.Name=="" || @User.Identity.Name==null)
        window.location.href = '/ACCLogin/Login/';


    var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/Main/GetLetterList",
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "fld_id", "value": boldMenu });
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                data: aoData,
                url: sSource,
                dataType: "json",
                success: fnCallback,
                error: function (response) {
                        window.location.href = '/ACCLogin/Login/';
                }
            })

        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function () {
            var UnBoldMenu = "#" + $("#unBoldMenu").val();
            $("#ulTreeview").find(UnBoldMenu).css('font-weight', 'normal');
        },
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
            if (aData["Flags"] == "4") {
                $('td', nRow).css('font-weight', 'bold');
            }
            if (aData["Status"] == "1") {
                $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');

            }
        },            
        "aoColumns": [

            {
                "mData": "fld_Id",
                "width": "1%"},
            {
                "mData": "ref_Id",
                "width": "1%" },
            {
                "mData": "Letter_Id",
                "width": "1%" },
            {
                "mData": "Flags",
                "width": "1%" },
            {
                "mData": "Status",
                "width": "1%" },
            {
                "mData": "ProjectCode",
                "width": "1%" },
            {
                "mData": "LetterType",
                "width": "1%" },
            {
                "mData": "Referrer",
                "width": "29%" },
            {
                "mData": "Ref_subject",
                "width": "30%" },
            {
                "mData": "Letter_subject",
                "width": "30%" },
            {
                "mData": "Date_Received",
                "width": "1%"  },                
            {
                "mData": "ref_Id",
                "width": "1%",
                "render": function (ref_Id, aoData, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a href="#" onclick="ViewLetter(' + ref_Id + ')" title="مشاهده نامه"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></li></a>'
                }
            }, {
                "mData": "ref_Id",
                "width": "1%",
                "render": function (ref_Id, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a href="#" onclick="ReferenceLetter(' + ref_Id + ')" title="ارجاع نامه"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></li></a>'
                }
            }
            , {
                "mData": "Letter_Id",
                "width": "1%",
                "render": function (Letter_Id, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a href="#" onclick="ReferenceList(' + Letter_Id + ')" title="گردش نامه"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet"></li></a>'
                }
            }

        ]
     })
        .columns.adjust();

    if (clicked_id!=-16)
        table.columns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]).visible(false); 
    else
        table.columns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4,12]).visible(false); 

}


var ViewLetter = function (refId) {        
        var url = "/Main/ViewLetter?Ref_Id=" + refId;
        $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
        $("#myModalBodyDiv").load(url, function () {
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
        })       
}

var ReferenceLetter = function (refId) {          
    var url = "/Main/ReferenceLetter?Ref_Id=" + refId;
            $("#myModalBodyDivRefer").load(url, function () {
                $("#myModalRefer").modal("show");
        })                  
}


var ReferenceList = function (letterId) {       
    var url = "/Main/ReferenceList?Letter_Id=" + letterId;
    $("#myModalBodyDivReferList").load(url, function () {
        $("#myModalReferList").modal("show");
    })                  
}
```

and problem solved. all the borwsers shows the same Table columns widths.